# Objects disappearing/reappearing behind transparent plane?

Tags: objects, transparency

I'm a total Blender/3D modeling newbie and this is my first ever project, so apologies if this is a really stupid question.

I'm making this promo for my band, got the bands logo on a plane made transparent with Alpha Blend, and an emission shader to make it glow like a neon sign. As you can see in the gif in the link below, as I pan the viewport (and the camera for the animation) around it, the flyers on the wall behind the logo are popping in and out of view. Any idea how to stop this?

https://ibb.co/34mtRKt

Thanks!

Comment: maybe the faces are overlapping, try to move the logo a bit forward

Comment: If you provide blend file we can tell you…